# Conceptual question about solutions to system of linear equations when $\det(A) = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to think of the solutions to a system of linear equations in a geometric/intuitive way but I can't seem to logically grasp it.

Say we have $Av =b$ where A is just any generic $3 \times 3$ matrix, and **b** and **v** exist in $\mathbb{R^3}$. I know that if $\det(A) \neq 0$ there exists any solutions to $b$ for any $v$ since essentially we're not "squishing the dimensions down" and our column space of $A$ is enough to get any solution. Now let's say $\det(A) = 0$, and let's say that the $\mbox{rk}(A)$ is $2$. So, I know that to have a solution $b$ must lie in this plane that has been squished down. I also know that this results in an infinite number of solutions, but why does this result to a solution line that has $\dim \ker(A)$ (which is $1$ in our case) number of free parameters?

Is this because the solutions space is comprised of the Kernel/Null Space too? But in this case, shouldn't we always have a solution when $\det(A) =0$, but I know this isn't always the case as sometimes there will be no solution to
$b$ for any $v$.

If anyone could shed light on this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two $n$-dimensional spaces, the domain and the codomain. The column space lives in the codomain. The kernel lives in the domain. Every solution of $A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{b}$ for $\mathbf{b}$ fixed is of the form $\mathbf{v}_0 + \mathbf{u}$ where $\mathbf{v}_0$ is a fixed particular solution and $\mathbf{u}$ is in the kernel of $A$. Hence the number of free parameters, when there is a solution at all, is the dimension of the kernel. So, you're asking why the dimension of the kernel plus the dimension of the column space is $n$.

You know the kernel gets smashed down to the origin in the codomain. You also know the whole domain gets smashed down to the column space.

Okay, now take the domain and imagine collapsing the kernel. For instance, if the kernel was the $z$-axis, that would result in just the $xy$-plane. In any case, we've now got an *injective* map from the collapsed domain to the codomain. But really it only hits the column space, so we've got a *bijective* map from the collapsed domain to the column space. The only way that ever happens is if the dimensions of the collapsed domain and the column space are the same, say $r$, the (column) rank of the matrix. But the dimension of the collapsed domain is $n-k$ where $k$ is the dimension of the kernel. Hence $r = n-k$, so $r+k=n$.

This is a standard proof of the rank-nullity theorem, phrased less algebraically than usual.

Comment: So if every solution is of the form $v_{0}+u$ why won't we always have a solution since the kernel of A will be non trivial. But then I also know that if our vector $b$ doesn't lie in the column space, we won't have any solutions.

Comment: @jambajuice Well, I said, "when there is a solution at all". You need a particular solution $\mathbf{v}_0$ to get the ball rolling. That exists (by definition) if and only if $\mathbf{b}$ is in the column space of $A$.

Comment: Right, so when **b** doesn't lie in our column space, then it doesn't matter how big our kernel is, there are absolutely no solutions whatsoever?